# Mailgun Email validation API in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I'm trying to put in node a curl command I've to use the Mailgun API for email validations, but when I make the request, the api never recognises the 'address' field as when curl does.

Here are the scripts and results:

Curl command

```
curl -s --user api:pubkey-5ogiflzbnjrljiky49qxsiozqef5jxp7 -G \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate \
    -d address='john.smith@gmail.com'
```

Node.js script

```
var request = require('request')
  , inspect = require('util').inspect

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate'
  , method: 'GET'
  , encoding: 'ASCII'
  // , body: "address=john.smith@gmail.com"
  , form: { address: "john.smith@gmail.com" }
  , auth: {
      username: "api"
    , password: "pubkey-5ogiflzbnjrljiky49qxsiozqef5jxp7"
  }
}
request(options, function (err, result){
  if(err){ console.log(err) }
  console.log(inspect(result.request.body.toString('utf8')))
  console.log(inspect(result.request.response.body))    
})
```

Expected output

```
{
  "is_valid": true,
  "parts": {
    "local_part": "johnsmith",
    "domain": "gmail.com",
    "display_name": null
  },
  "address": "john.smith@gmail.com",
  "did_you_mean": null
}
```

Output I get

```
'address=john.smith%40gmail.com'
'{\n  "message": "Missing parameter: address"\n}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback.

The form parameter sets the body of the request, but for a GET request, you want to pass parameters on the query string. Use the `qs` parameter instead of `form` for GET requests:

```
var request = require('request')
  , inspect = require('util').inspect

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate'
  , method: 'GET'
  , qs: {address: 'john.smith@gmail.com'}
  , encoding: 'ASCII'
  , auth: {
      username: "api"
    , password: "pubkey-5ogiflzbnjrljiky49qxsiozqef5jxp7"
  }
}
request(options, function (err, result){
  if(err){ console.log(err) }
  console.log(inspect(result.request.response.body))
})
```